# Biblatex Citation Problem

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have my bibliography contained in my LaTeX document, as

```
\usepackage{biblatex}

Words... \cite{ref1}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ref1}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

I've done this many times in the past, but for some reason, my citations are not returning the reference number, but `\cite{ref1}` returns `[ref1]` instead.  Anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If I am not wrong, to use the environment `thebibliography` you don't need any package neither to run `biblatex`. Try to delete the `aux` files.

Comment: @Sigur: Fantastic, you're right!  I deleted the aux files, removed the biblatex package from the preamble, and now all is perfect.  Thanks!!